# Написание текста после команды

Tags: c#, .net

Мне необходима помощь в создании проекта. Сам проект я делаю на C# и у меня появилась проблема.

Проблема заключается в том что я не знаю как вывести текст после команды, в textbox1.

Вот как всё работает я ввожу что то в textbox1, и программа выводит. Если внутри textbox строка Write в начале текста есть, то программа выводит строку которая находиться в сопках - '(текст)' и завершается двоеточием - ';'.

Вот пример: Write(Hello, world!); Вывод Hello, world! Но идея заключается в том чтобы сделать командную строку на C#, так что нужно чтобы код был гибким.

К примеру вместо вывода текста был вывод сообщения командой MessageBox(); Или выключать компьютер командой ComputerOFF();.

Ещё хотел упомянуть то что команда MessageBox(); Должна выводить сообщение с двумя параметрами. К примеру: MessageBox("Hello", "world"); Вывод:
[image: Пример Вывода]

Ну надеюсь вы меня поняли заранее спасибо!

Comment: То есть вам нужен интерпретатор. Вы можете сами его попробовать реализовать или воспользоваться готовыми решениями

Comment: Хотел бы самому попробовать но где взять нужную информацию? И не был бы не против готовых исходников.

Comment: Ну, я как то в проекте использовал http://www.antlr.org. Описывал грамматику, генерировал код парсера. Не знаю, подойдет ли вам это, но поглядеть стоит.